# How can masterbranch know what my stackoverflow e-mail is ? ( or is not )

Tags: discussion, support, security

I log into https://www.masterbranch.com  and it has this option to link my stackoverflow user, but it ask me to type my email ( probably just to avoid me pointint to Jon's )

I type some random email for I don't want them to have my email but they notice it wasn't the one I use in SO.

How could they?

[image: This is what it shows]

My guess, is they fetch the gravatar from stackoverflow and the gravatar from the email I type, but I don't really know if that makes sense.

Is there a security hole in StackOverflow?

Comment: Now, that is my email! How did you get to know it?

Comment: from your OpenID maybe?

Comment: I tried too, but it didn't fill my email address. I used ClaimID, though, to log in.

Comment: I don't know, I used openid.stackexchange ... I have a different email in openid.stackexchange and in stackoverflow ( or my gravatar for that matter )

Comment: Gravatar uses a hash of the email, so if they know the hashing algorithm, they could just run it themselves and compare the two results. Not 100% accurate but close enough.

Comment: @mmyers: That's my idea. They don't even need to know the algorithm, they can get the image and compare it directly, but, I wonder if this is what they did. BTW, I'm glad you rolledback your user name... :) :) :) :) No no don't kill me ......:I

Answer (score 6):

As Michael J. Myers said:

> Gravatar uses a hash of the email, so if they know the hashing algorithm, they could just run it themselves and compare the two results. Not 100% accurate but close enough.

This is like storing a hash of your password, it doesn't mean they know your password, just that the hashes match.. etc.

Comment: Pretty obvious, in retrospect.  A bit creepy if you don't know what's going on.